# Checking when the content of an iframe has been loaded

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I wanted to know is it possible to check when the content in an iframe is loaded.

I have a hidden iframe and I don't want to show it until the webpage/website inside the iframe has loaded.

i tried the following, not really worked for me:

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
    ;
});
```

is that possible?

Comment: Did you put it within `$(document).ready(...`?

Comment: See if this can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249680/how-to-check-if-iframe-is-loaded-or-it-has-a-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done cross domain, only locally.

```
<iframe src="/amp" id="iframeID"></iframe>

document.getElementById("iframeID").contentWindow.onload = function(){
    alert('loaded');
};
```