# Determine that a page inside iframe on server-side

Tags: asp.net, iframe, webforms

I found the similar questions but no answer

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Text
    </div>
        <iframe src="FramedPage.aspx" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to determine that FramedPage.aspx is loaded by iframe on server-side?
I can't use `referrer` http header because it doesn't work in some cases for me.
Also I try to access by Parent property but it is null...
Do you have any ideas how I can detect iframe on server-side? Thanks.

Comment: For some reasons I also can't use custom url parameter

Comment: I believe this is completely impossible due to you having no control over the client. All you will know is the information provided in the request, which could even be deliberately falsified.

Comment: This has been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249680/how-to-check-if-iframe-is-loaded-or-it-has-a-content