# Check if URL is loaded through iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible in some way to detect if a URL is loaded via. iframe?

For instance to check, if domain.com is loaded or not loaded (if the site doesn't allow iframe loading of the website)?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to detect if your own site is being framed by another?

Comment: No. If I frame another site, then I would like to detect if it's loaded or not

Comment: Ah OK I understand. Please see my answer below in that case.

Comment: Please view this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249680/how-to-check-if-iframe-is-loaded-or-it-has-a-content

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, the requirement is to detect when another site is loaded successfully in an IFrame under your control.

You can achieve that by simply hooking into the IFrame's `onload` event.

Example:

```
<script>
function frameLoaded() {
   alert("IFrame loaded.");
}
</script>

<iframe onload="frameLoaded()" src="https://www.bing.com"></iframe>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d1z62ctw/