# How to hear from `iframe` content change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

There is a `angularjs` application, I am working out of it. in my web page, I am getting application loaded in the `iframe` - I just want to know whether the `ifame` loaded or not. for that, I use:

//but i don't like this.

```
 var myTimeout = function () {
         setTimeout(function(){
             if($('.ssueContentIframe').length > 0 ) {
                  penetrate();
                  return;
             }
             myTimeout();
         }, 10000);
     };

    myTimeout();
```

in the `iframe` there is number of content keep loading and changing. But one of the event I would require to add in the element with class name of `.ui-grid-icon-ok` - how can I hear from `document` that the `element existence` - any one help me?

Comment: What are the URLs of the parent page, and the document in the iframe? There are CORS, XSS and other rules in place to prevent you from stepping inside or outside of frames for very good reasons. If they're from the same host on the same protocol, you can be helped. The function name `penetrate` does not bode well for your possibilities, however.

Comment: It's all are same URL and there is no issue with CORS or anything.

Comment: What does `penetrate` do currently? Is it defined?

Comment: If you can edit the aplication that you load in the iframe than you can use postMessage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: @TylerY86 - it is a function. it checking the iframe, once the iframe available it calls the `penetrate()` :: to do this - i keep calling the setTimeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's no constraints CORS or XSS, you should be able to do something like the following.

```js
var what = document.getElementById('what');

function checkIframeLoaded() {
  try {
    // Get a handle to the iframe element
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

    what.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Checking...\n"));

    // Check if loading is complete
    if (iframeDoc.readyState == 'complete') {
      afterLoading();
      return;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }
  // If we are here, it is not loaded. Set things up so we check   the status again in 100 milliseconds
  window.setTimeout(checkIframeLoaded, 100);
}

function afterLoading() {
  what.appendChild(document.createTextNode("It loaded!\n"));
}

checkIframeLoaded();
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="data:text/plain,"></iframe>
<pre id="what">Not loaded.</pre>
```

If there are any constraints (e.g. sandboxing, CORS, XSS, etc.), you'll get an alert dialog every 10th of a second with the error, and I hope you have the ability to click the checkbox to ignore them. :)

Note: This is a modified version of [this other stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249680/how-to-check-if-iframe-is-loaded-or-it-has-a-content), expanded to demonstrate errors.

Comment: Fixed some copypasta; had "iframe" where I should have had "what".