# PHP / jQuery : Unable to manipulate foreign form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to submit a connection form from another website in order to display some informations available when you're only connected.

First of all, I'm already tried to make a CURL call but it was rejected by the form.
So, now I'm trying to display it in a `iframe` and I want to know when connection is good without to get blocked by the Firefox protection.

I don't know if best solution is to get the current URL displayed or not while I've tried this :

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('iframe').load(function(){

            var content = $('iframe').contents().search('Welcome');
            console.log(content);
        });
    });
```

But I'm again blocked by Firefox who say :

> Error: Permission denied to access property "document"

Someone has an other idea or a tips to resolve my trouble ?

Thanks guys

Comment: I think you're not supposed to be able to do what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: In fact, my first goal is to check if form return "Connection is ok " or not ^^

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249680/how-to-check-if-iframe-is-loaded-or-it-has-a-content

That will help answer that question and checks to see if it's loaded a couple different ways.