# Listen to see if content from external js file is loaded in DOM for javascript to use

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run javascript on a form that is loaded in content coming from an external js file, but it's failing because content doesn't load right away

I've tried listening for the load of the html button in the iframe, but not getting anything:

```
document.querySelector('#hyform button').addEventListener('load', function() {

    console.log('external js content loaded');

}
```

UPDATED QUESTION. This is not an iframe but content loaded from an external js file. I dont have control of the external js file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if iframe is loaded or it has a content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249680/how-to-check-if-iframe-is-loaded-or-it-has-a-content)

Comment: I'd imagine, in your example, that you're attaching a `load` event to an element that doesn't exist yet. You'd probably want to attach it to the iframe instead.

Comment: In the iframe itself, add a body onload function which calls a function in the iframe's parent to let the parent DOM know iframe has loaded

Comment: I've edited my question. It's not an iframe. It's content that is loading from an external js file.

Comment: That's a huge difference!

Comment: Are you using $(document).ready() or document.readyState === 'complete' ?

Comment: If you don't control that Javascript file or have an option to provide a function that this script will call at some point it _itself_ defines (some 3rd parties provide such an option), there's no viable way to do this.

Comment: No jquery is allowed. I'm not in control of the javascript file, but I know the content that it loads and am wondering if I can just check for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically append the file to `<head>`, then monitor the load state:

```
var callback = function () {
    // do stuff
};

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'path_to_file.js'
script.type = 'text/javascript';

if (script.readyState) {
    if (script.readyState === 'loaded' || script.readyState === 'complete') {
        callback();
        script.onreadystatechange = null;
    }
} else {
    script.onload = function () {
        callback();
    };
}


document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```