# Testcafe: Content of the iframe to which you are switching did not load

Tags: testing, iframe, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Testcafe v 1.9.4
When run test locally everything ok
Wneh run via GitLab:

```
1) Content of the iframe to which you are switching did not load.
      Browser: Chrome 86.0.4240.111 / Linux 0.0
      
         119 |
         120 |
         121 |        await t.expect(this.cke1.exists).ok({timeout:60000})
         122 |        await
      t.expect(this.cke1.visible).ok({timeout:60000})
         123 |
       > 124 |        await t.switchToIframe(this.cke1);
```

I add :        await t.eval(() => location.reload(true));
But it is not helpful
This issue appeared around one week ago. Before it was ok too. Code did not change long time
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

This error may be caused by the fact that the loading of an iframe document takes too much time. I suppose that the CI machine has not much CPU and memory resources, so the test may be unstable. I suggest you increase the iframe selector timeout: [Wait Until an  Is Loaded](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/switchtoiframe.html#wait-until-an-iframe-is-loaded). Also, you can try implementing a ClientFunction with the workaround described at [How to check if iframe is loaded or it has a content?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10444444/10684943) to wait while iframe content is loading.

Comment: I think the problem is in Testcafe v 1.10.1. Because before I used locally prev version of Testcafe and it worked fine. Today I've update and now test fails locally too with same issue

Comment: How did you set the timeout? Your code snippet does not illustrate it. Did you implement the ClientFunction that is waiting for the iFrame? How?

Comment: In Gitlab now last version:
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ node --version
v14.15.3
$ testcafe --version
1.10.1
$ /opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh chromium:headless  tests/announceTest.js   --skip-js-errors
 Running tests in:
 - Chrome 86.0.4240.111 / Linux 0.0
 Smoke tests - Announcements tests
 ✖ 001 | Add Announce Template
   1) Content of the iframe to which you are switching did not load.

Comment: Install prev vers of Testcafe and test passed: 
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
02:42
$ node --version
v14.15.3
$ testcafe --version
1.10.1
$ npm i testcafe@1.9.4
$ testcafe --version
1.9.4
$ /opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh chromium:headless  tests/announceTest.js   --skip-js-errors
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
 Running tests in:
 - Chrome 86.0.4240.111 / Linux 0.0
 Smoke tests - Announcements tests
Fill name Of Announce test_dcm1/5/2021
Fill subject Of Announce test_dcm1/5/2021
Fill cte of Announce test_dcm1/5/2021
Template is created

Comment: cke1 = Selector('#cke_1_contents > iframe',{timeout:120000}) ;
I don't now how to add screenshot, where you can see that iframe is loaded  really. But Tetscafe v1.10 fails on it and Testcafe1.9.4 passes

Comment: It looks like an issue with TestCafe. Could you please share a simple example so I can reproduce the issue locally?

Comment: I don't know how can I share intranet page: "<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, id_content_en" aria-describedby="cke_47" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>"
cke1 = Selector('#cke_1_contents > iframe',{timeout:120000}) ;
 await t.expect(this.cke1.exists).ok({timeout:60000})
 await t.switchToIframe(this.cke1);
 await t.typeText(Selector('body'), cteText[0], { replace: true, speed: 0.5});
 await t.switchToMainWindow();

Comment: Since this problem looks like a TestCafe bug, I suggest you [create an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md) in a testcafe github repository. Please try to create a simple example based on your web site code, which demonstrates the problematic behavior and send it to support@devexpress.com or attach to the issue.