# How can I tell if element is rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, virtual-dom

I have simple html

```
<div class="main-app"></div>
<button class="btn"> CLICKME </button>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

another html to load: contact.html:

```
<div class="contact">
    this is contact component
</div>
```

and javascript:

```
function load_component() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("main-app")[0].innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="./contact.html" ></object>';
    // here is when I want to check if this particular content is ready
    var loader = setInterval(function () {
        if(document.getElementsByTagName("object")[0].readyState !== "complete") return;
        clearInterval(loader);
     }, 300);
}

document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    load_component();
});
```

As you see on following screen it creates whole html dom (#document) inside our html. How can I check if that document is ready?

and here is screen from inspect element of added html:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Comment: @MikeS. No, I tried to use it. But this #document is something like in iFrames. It's dom inside dom...

Comment: You should use an iframe not an object, the you can [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249680/how-to-check-if-iframe-is-loaded-or-it-has-a-content)