# Getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'contentDocument')" error

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I'm following the answer to: [How to check if iframe is loaded or it has a content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249680/how-to-check-if-iframe-is-loaded-or-it-has-a-content)

But I keep getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'contentDocument')`

The iframe's ID is correct too, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Note that the `<script>` inside `.vzPlayer` creates the iframe within `.voiceDemos`.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
<div class="vzPlayer">
      <script>
        var CSS_THEME = "//voicezam.com/CSPlayer/style/Headless.css"

        /* Enter your account ID. You can find this under the Menu item: Help | About */
        var ACCOUNT_ID = 'REDACTED';

        /* Enter the title of this page. All events will appear in your Zamtistics */
        var PAGE_NAME = 'Demos page for REDACTED';

        /* The value of RENDER_MODE may be either 'inline' (default) OR 'popup' */
        var RENDER_MODE = 'inline';

        /* The DEFAULT_DEMO value may be:*/
        /*   null - (default) - Display the top Demo as listed in your Showcase */
        /*   xxxx - (Demo Category ID) - Display this Demo when the player launches */
        /*           note: The Category ID is listed under the Demo's gear icon with in your Showcase */
        /*      0 - Displays the Player's Demo playlist when the player launches */
        /*           note: Demos are listed in the order defined within your Showcase */

        var DEFAULT_DEMO = null;  /* (default); */

        /* If presenting on mobile device, use vertical player and offer Category playlist */
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("vzCodeBlock")[0].offsetWidth <= 600) {
          DEFAULT_DEMO = 0;
          PLAYER_STYLE = '03';
        }

        /* Option to show Contacts panel in player */
        var SHOW_CONTACTS = true;

      </script>

      <script src="//www.voicezam.com/clientScripts/WebLinking2.aspx"></script>

      <div id="voiceDemos" style="width:100%; height:324px"></div>

      <!-- Note: Optional codeline below asserting player <DIV> at 100% -->
      <!-- <div id="voiceDemos" style="width:100%;"></div> -->

    </div>

<script>
var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
// device detection
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) { 
    isMobile = true;
}

function checkIframeLoaded() {console.log('000000000000');
    // Get a handle to the iframe element
    var iframe = document.getElementById('ZAMPLAYER_IFRAME_MEDIAZAM');
    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    console.log('1111111111111');

    // Check if loading is complete
    if (  iframeDoc.readyState  == 'complete' ) {console.log('22222222222');
        // The loading is complete, call the function we want executed once the iframe is loaded
        afterLoading();
        return;
    } 

    // If we are here, it is not loaded. Set things up so we check the status again in 100 milliseconds
    console.log('333333333');
    window.setTimeout(checkIframeLoaded, 100);
}

function afterLoading(){console.log('44444444');
    document.getElementById("ZAMPLAYER_IFRAME_MEDIAZAM").setAttribute('style','width:777px');
}

if(!isMobile){
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      checkIframeLoaded();
    });
}
</script>
```

(`isMobile` is defined as false.

And the last console.log() message I get in the console when running this code is `000000000000`.

I don't even get the console.log() messages of: `1111111111111`, `22222222222`, `333333333`, and `44444444`)

Comment: if the iframe is cross origin there's absolutely no way to access it directly like you are trying - and if an error is thrown, the code afterwards would not run, of course

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah the iframe created is cross origin. hmm... is there a way to figure out if the iframe has loaded and exists before changing the height of the iframe itself? a delay of 5000 milliseconds seem to work, but I want to make sure even devices that load more slowly will work.

Comment: Cross origin may be a problem, but it's not this problem. You should have an iframe variable OK. Are you running the script before all the HTML is loaded? Where do you load your script?

Comment: @AHaworth hi, i've edited the original post to include all the code.

Comment: You havent shown your HTML - it's important to know exactly where that is loaded.

Comment: @AHaworth the ```<script>``` inside ```.vzPlayer``` creates the iframe within ```.voiceDemos```.

Comment: Are you sure it is there? Do you see it in your browser dev tools inspect facility?

Comment: @AHaworth yup i've confirmed via my browser's Inspect, the iframe is nested within the ```.voiceDemos``` div

Comment: Is something asynchronous going on? And what does console.log(iframe) show you [just in case there is a browser error on the error message :)]

Comment: @AHaworth I'm not sure if something asynchronous is going on (though I do suspect some async stuff going on, yes), but the console.log came out with the iframe's HTML code